# How to add a cookie to DefaultHttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, cookies, asp.net-core

I have a function that expect HttpRequest as parameter:

```
public string Read(HttpRequest req)
{
  if (req.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
  {
    return req.Headers[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ajaxsession"]];
  }

  return req.Cookies[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cookiename"]];
}
```

I wrote a unit test

```
[Test]
public void ReadSessionToken_BrowserRequest_ExpectSidToken()
{
  var repo = new DefaultHttpContext();
}
```

My question is, how to add a cookie to `repo.Request.Cookies`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I didn't test but in github repo there is a [test](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/5f75c07bbff7824275c1486c3cc03f0df3eef3af/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Tests/Internal/DefaultHttpRequestTests.cs#L166) for set and get cookie:

```
var newCookies = new[] { "name0=value0%2C", "%5Ename1=value1" };
request.Headers["Cookie"] = newCookies;
```

**Update**

Tested and worked.

Comment: One more question, what is newCookies for a type, array?

Comment: It is a string array (`string[]`).